# Como verificar se um array possui um atributo?

Tags: php, array, laravel, laravel-5, validação

Estou usando *Laravel 5.4* em uma aplicação, e um método validador recebe um *array*.

Esse *array* pode ter os atributos:

```
[
    'nome' => $request->nome,
    'ddd'  => $request->ddd,
    'fone' => $request->fone
]
```

Ou somente:

```
[
    'nome' => $request->nome
]
```

Como faço para verificar se ele vem com os atributos `ddd` e `fone`, já que se ele não vem com esses atributos  ele volta **Undefined index**.

Obs. Sei que posso criar um novo método e validar eles separados, porém quero utilizar apenas um método.

Função para validação:

```
private function validaComTelefone($data)
{
    $regras = [
        'nome' => 'required',
        'ddd' => 'required|min:2|max:2',
        'fone' => 'required|min:8|max:9'
    ];

    $mensagens = [
        'nome.required' => 'Campo nome é obrigatório',
        'ddd.required' => 'Campo ddd é obrigatório',
        'ddd.min' => 'Campo ddd deve ter 2 dígitos',
        'ddd.max' => 'Campo ddd deve ter 2 dígitos',
        'fone.required' => 'Campo telefone é obrigatório',
        'fone.min' => 'Campo telefone deve ter ao menos 8 dígitos',
        'fone.max' => 'Campo telefone deve ter no máximo 9 dígitos'
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, $regras, $mensagens);
}
```

Comment: Se você está colocando "required", os índices são obrigatórios, caso não existam, o Validator passa os valores para o MessageBag, não deve ser sua validação que está cusando o `Undefined Index`, você consegue por o log completo (numero da linha e amostra) ou mesmo o fragmento que está usar a sua função na pergunta? e pra verificar se existe você pode usar o `array_key_exists`

Comment: é que se vier ddd entao ddd e fone são obrigatorios, acredito que terei que mudar minha lógica. Por isso preciso saber como verificar se existe um atributo desses no array

Comment: Ah, o laravel tem filtros corretos para isso, como o `required_with`, vou dar uma organizada numa resposta.

Comment: @Pliavi resolvi com o array_key_exists, vou por uma resposta com ele, mas aguardo a sua solução :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após conversa no chat, foi verificado que o caso era obrigar o usuário a ter o telefone caso o DDD tenha sido 
informado.

Para isso, é possível se utilizar da regra de validação [`required_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-with) que faz com que um campo se torne obrigatório caso qualquer um informado na
regra esteja presente.

Como no exemplo utilizando o próprio código do autor da pergunta:

```
$regras = [
    'nome' => 'required',
    'ddd' => 'required_with:fone|min:2|max:2',
    'fone' => 'required_with:ddd|min:8|max:9'
];
```

#### O que está sendo verificado agora?

O **nome** continua sendo obrigatório, porém **fone** só passa
  ser obrigatório caso **ddd** seja informado e *vice-versa*.

Em resposta ao título da pergunta, para verificar a existência de um índice dentro de um array é possível utilizar 
o método do PHP [`array_key_exists`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp):

Caso o índice exista, retorna `TRUE`

```
$valores = [
    'nome' => $request->nome,
    'ddd'  => $request->ddd,
    'fone' => $request->fone
]

echo array_key_exists('ddd', $valores) // True
```

Caso contrário, `FALSE`

```
$valores = [
    'nome' => $request->nome,
]

echo array_key_exists('ddd', $valores) // False
```

Comment: Haha, já havia resolvido com o array_key_exists(), mas sua resposta ficou mais completa

Comment: @FelipePaetzold
O `array_key_exists` quebra um galho, mas já fica aí pra caso tenha mais pra frente um formulário grande, onde tenha uma maior interdependência dos campos, porque começa a ficar treta a parada :v 
Vou colocar o link da documentação, porque tem várias regras interessantes para validação que podem ser úteis pra você no futuro

Comment: Pois é, na verdade estou desenvolvendo essa aplicação apenas para montar um curso, normalmente faria mais elaborada essa validação, e também validaria com javascript, porém é um curso bem simples, para iniciantes no framework ^^.